# How to compile a modified kernel which is different from the one installed on our computer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am currently working on linux kernel 3.11.0-12. But I am adding a system call by modifying the source code I downloaded from kernel.org of linux-2.6.26. I want to compile the modified 2.6.26 kernel to test my new system call. How should i do it?

Comment: As a general suggestion, re-build the existing kernel *unmodified* before you try to change anything.  That way *when* you run into problems you will know if they are with your *procedure* or with your *changes*.

Comment: There are plenty of references on how to build the kernel. Please pick one, follow it. Then if something goes wrong, you can post a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0):

1)If you want to build kernel for same architecture on which you are working then..

go into your linux source folder and fire below commands....

To Clean:
make distclean

To write config:

make  defconfig

To build Kernel:

make  uImage

or make vmlinux which image you want to build

2)for arm architecture...

To Clean:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- distclean

To write config:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- defconfig

To build Kernel:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage

3) using  second step you can build linux kernel for any platform with any toolchain
 just use ARCH= CROSS_COMPILE= macro as per requirement......

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a vanilla kernel and that you are working on a module. Vanilla or not, you need the configuration file for the target kernel.

Just download the source, copy the kernel configuration file to `<kernel_source>/.config` and build the kernel once, since you need the configuration- and header-files for an out of kernel source build. Use `make modules_prepare`.

Then run `make -C <full_path_to_kernel_source> M=$PWD` to build the module.

Take a look at [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for more detailed information.

Comment: I don't believe you can add a syscall with a module (other than by crudely attacking the dispatch mechanism), so this seems like an invalid assumption.